# angularjs - table isn't appearing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an application in AngularJS (I'm begginer..sorry!) that needs to show diferents tables when I click on the menu.

**Problem**: simulado1.htm is appearing when I click in the menu, but its table isn't.

What should I do?

It's a SPA using the ng-route and

Thanks everybody!

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html ng-app="app1">
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script src="scripts/route-config.js"></script>
            <script src="scripts/table.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
        </head>   
        <header>
            <h2>MEDGRUPO</h2>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <div id="menu-simulados">
                <ul> <!-- This is a menu to choose which "simulado" (table) you want to -->
                <li><a href="#!simulado1">Simulado 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!simulado2">Simulado 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!simulado3">Simulado 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <body ng-app="myModule">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </body>
        </html>
            // ARCHIVE route-config.js //
            var app = angular.module("app1", ["ngRoute"]);
            app.config(function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                    .when("/", {
                        templateUrl : "main.htm",
                        controller : "MainCtrl",
                    })
                    .when("/simulado1", {
                        templateUrl : "simulado1.htm",
                        controller : "Sim1Ctrl",
                    })
                    .when("/simulado2", {
                        templateUrl : "simulado2.htm",
                        controller : "Sim2Ctrl",
                    })
                    .when("/simulado3", {
                        templateUrl : "simulado3.htm",
                        controller : "Sim3Ctrl",
                    });
            });
```

Here it's my archive table.js with the table parameters:

```
            //<reference path="angular.js" />
            var app = angular.module("myModule", []).controller("myController", function ($scope) {
                var tabela = [
                    { posicao: "1", nota: "10", matricula: "897413", especialidade: "clinica medica", turma: "2008 MEDCURSO SALVADOR - Turma A/2008 MED SALVADOR" , filial:"Salvador (BA)" },
                    { posicao: "2", nota: "40", matricula: "897413", especialidade: "cardiologia", turma: "2008 MEDCURSO SP - Turma A/2008 MED SP", filial:"São Paulo (SP)" },
                    { posicao: "3", nota: "50", matricula: "205500", especialidade: "cardiologia", turma: "2008 MEDCURSO SP - Turma A/2007 MED SP" , filial:"São Paulo (SP)"},
                    { posicao: "4", nota: "90", matricula: "897413", especialidade: "pediatria", turma: "2008 MEDCURSO NATAL - Turma A/2008 MED NATAL", filial:"Natal (RN)" },
                    { posicao: "5", nota: "80", matricula: "205500", especialidade: "clinica medica", turma: "2008 MEDCURSO NATAL - Turma A/2005 MED NATAL", filial:"Natal (RN)" },
                    { posicao: "6", nota: "70", matricula: "897416", especialidade: "clinica medica", turma: "2008 MEDCURSO NATAL - Turma A/2008 MED NATAL", filial:"Natal (RN)" },
                    { posicao: "7", nota: "10", matricula: "205500", especialidade: "clinica medica", turma: "2008 MEDCURSO SALVADOR - Turma A/2006 MED SALVADOR", filial:"Salvador (BA)" },
                    { posicao: "8", nota: "10", matricula: "897413", especialidade: "urologia", turma: "2008 MEDCURSO SALVADOR - Turma A/2008 MED SALVADOR", filial:"Salvador (BA)" },
                    { posicao: "9", nota: "50", matricula: "897415", especialidade: "clinica medica", turma: "2008 MEDCURSO SALVADOR - Turma A/2008 MED SALVADOR", filial:"Salvador (BA)" },
                ];
                $scope.tabela = tabela;
            });
```

// archive simulado1.htm //

```
  <body ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    Entre com sua Matrícula :  
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText.matricula" placeholder="Pesquisar matricula" />

    <br><br><br>

    <span>
          <select ng-model="searchText.especialidade">
            <option value="">Especialidades - Todas</option>
            <option value="cardiologia">cardiologia</option>
            <option value="clinica medica">clinica medica</option>
            <option value="pediatria">pediatria</option>
            <option value="urologia">urologia</option>
          </select>
     </span>
     <span>
          <select ng-model="searchText.turma">
            <option value="">Turmas - Todas</option>
            <option value="2008 MEDCURSO SALVADOR - Turma A/2008 MED SALVADOR">2008 MEDCURSO SALVADOR - Turma A/2008 MED SALVADOR</option>
            <option value="2008 MEDCURSO Natal - Turma A/2008 MED NATAL">2008 MEDCURSO Natal - Turma A/2008 MED NATAL</option>
            <option value="2008 MEDCURSO SP - Turma A/2008 MED SP">2008 MEDCURSO SP - Turma A/2008 MED SP</option>
            <option value="2008 MEDCURSO SP - Turma A/2007 MED SP">2008 MEDCURSO SP - Turma A/2007 MED SP</option>
            <option value="2008 MEDCURSO NATAL - Turma A/2008 MED NATAL">2008 MEDCURSO NATAL - Turma A/2008 MED NATAL</option>
            <option value="2008 MEDCURSO NATAL - Turma A/2005 MED NATAL">2008 MEDCURSO NATAL - Turma A/2005 MED NATAL</option>
            <option value="2008 MEDCURSO SALVADOR - Turma A/2006 MED SALVADOR">2008 MEDCURSO SALVADOR - Turma A/2006 MED SALVADOR</option>
            <option value="2008 MEDCURSO SALVADOR - Turma A/2008 MED SALVADOR">2008 MEDCURSO SALVADOR - Turma A/2008 MED SALVADOR</option>
          </select>
    </span>
    <span>
          <select ng-model="searchText.filial">
            <option value="">Filiais - Todas</option>
            <option value="Natal">Natal</option>
            <option value="Salvador">Salvador</option>
            <option value="SP">SP</option>
          </select>
    </span>

    <br><br><br>

    <span style="width:100%" onclick="imprimir()" class="imprimir">Imprimir |</span>





    <div id="tabelaimpressao">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Posição</th>
                <th>Nota</th>
                <th>Matrícula</th>
                <th>Especialidade</th>
                <th>Turma</th>
                <th>Filial</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="simulado in tabela | filter:searchText">
                <td> {{ simulado.posicao }} </td>
                <td> {{ simulado.nota }} </td>
                <td> {{ simulado.matricula  }} </td>
                <td> {{ simulado.especialidade  }} </td>
                <td> {{ simulado.turma  }} </td>
                <td> {{ simulado.filial  }} </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Where did you use `$scope.tabela`? Could you show your view page?

Comment: Can u share the code of simulado1.htm?

Comment: Sorry for forgeting the archive simulado1.htm and its code. I edited the question. Thanks everybody for being keen to help me. I wish happy New year for everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two fixes:
1. I removed line 9 from index.html because you were linking 2 times the angular file.
2. Corrected your controller's statement without declaring a new module. As:

`app.controller ("myController", function ($ scope) {`

There your table loaded by clicking on the link.

Answer (score 0):

In simulado1.htm no need to set the **`ng-app`** and **`ng-controller`** again as you are setting the routes in the router config.

```
 <body ng-app="myModule"> //remove this
 <div ng-controller="myController"> //remove this
```

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan. Thanks for helping me.

I removed both but index.html is just showing the html content and not the angular content: `var app = angular.module("myModule", []).controller("myController", function ($scope) {
                var tabela = [...]`. Then I can see the whole HTML content of simulado1.htm but the table isn't appearing.